# Can gsuite admins define email delegates?

Tags: email, g-suite, delegation

All of Google's documentation details how to enable delegation for an organization, however I want to know if there's a way for an administrator to define delegates for an account.

My org has a handful of directory accounts that serve as mailboxes for departments, and department members/directors have a shared password for that email account. I'm working on phasing them out in lieu of groups used as forwarding addresses, but since I like a paper trail I want to keep the accounts as read-only mailboxes but instead delegate access to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own code to do that [using Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings), or use an existing third-party tool - [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM), for example, can [manage delegates](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/ExamplesEmailSettings#delegates).